# dealing at the same time with list and vector of object

Tags: c++, list, class, vector

I have to create a mini poker game. I created two classes `Card` and `Hand`.

I tried to deal one card to every player using for_each loop but compiler write that push_back doesn't match the argument list. I tried different option but don't success. How can I solve this problem?

Moreover, I have to write a function that tell when a player has a flush, so that there is more than 5 cards with same suit including suit that are already on the table. Card one table are represented by 'Hand pot'. For this thing I have to use `suits vector`. I don't know how to start to do this function.

Can you explain steps I have to do in order to achieve such a function.

```
enum Suit
{
    SPADES = 0, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS
};
class Card //Card
{
public:
    int number;
    Suit suit;
};
class Hand //One person
{
public:
    vector<Card> cards;
    int money;
};

vector<Card> Join(Hand a, Hand b)
{
    vector<Card> ab;
    for (auto it = a.cards.begin(); it < a.cards.end(); it++)
        ab.push_back(*it);
    for (auto it = b.cards.begin(); it < b.cards.end(); it++)
        ab.push_back(*it);
    return ab;
}
int main()
{
    stack<Card> deck;
    list<Hand> players;
    Hand pot;
    for (auto it = players.begin(); it != players.end(); it++)
    {
        players.push_back((*it).cards.push_back(deck.pop()));  //This line cause that I can't compile code
    }

    vector<Suit> suits = { SPADES, HEARTS, CLUBS, DIAMONDS };
    //Here I have to write code that display which player has a flush
}
```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I already use push_back and push_front in list, and work. So i don't think this is the problem

Comment: You are calling `(*it).cards.push_back(deck.pop())`, and then try to take the return value of this call and pass it to `players.push_back`. But that first call does not return any result: `push_back` is declared to return `void`. So this line doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Further, `players` list is empty. If and when you get this code to compile, that loop won't run and won't do anything anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the compiler errors you're seeing try this:

```
    for (auto it = players.begin(); it != players.end(); it++)
    {
        // use deck.top() here instead of deck.pop()
        it->cards.push_back(deck.top());
        
        // then pop after you've push_back'd
        deck.pop();
    }
```